# How to login into a computing node within a `SGE` cluster using ssh terminal?

Tags: sungridengine

I have the privilege to login into a submitting node in a `SGE` cluster. But I found I couldn't login into any computing node in the same `SGE` cluster. I have searched in `Google` and have been confirmed that in the network of computing nodes, it would have `ssh` right to connect between each two node of this network, then the job would run with the `MPI` environment. So why couldn't I connect anyone of the computing nodes using `ssh` terminal? When I tried to connect, the error message is `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`. Is it because that the configuration have prevented the common user to do this operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `qrsh -q \*@hostname`. Replace the `hostname` with the actual hostname.

Comment: use "qhost" to get the lsit of host names